# Fragment's properties are not injected when launching fragment with Robolectric and Dagger Hilt

Tags: android, dagger, dagger-hilt

Late init fields are not injected in fragment when launch fragment with **Robolectric** and **Dagger Hilt** .

I have a following test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@HiltAndroidTest
@Config(application = HiltTestApplication::class)
class SampleTest {

    @Test
    fun checkFragmentProperty() {
        launchFragmentInHiltContainer<TestFragment> {
            // nothing
        }
    }
}
```

and my TestFragment looks like this:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class TestFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var testClass: TestClass

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        testClass.some()
    }
}
```

When i try to run this test then it displays error `kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property testClass has not been initialized`

I use `launchFragmentInHiltContainer` method from the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-testing#launchfragment) but the same effect is when i just use `lunchFragmentInContainer` method from `androidx.fragment.app.testing`.

When i use emulator instead Robolectric then fields are injected correctly.

I tried to add:

```
hilt {
    enableTransformForLocalTests = true
}
```

and run tests from the console but test still fails

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I'm pretty sure onCreate is not being called in the test. Because this is an ActivityScenario.launch there is no `scenario.moveToState(State.CREATED)` possibility.

Comment: not sure if that's the reason but have you seen this? https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup.html#running-with-android-studio

Comment: @lukjar,did you manage to get any solution for it, if yes, please share as well